# JavaScript algorithm keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, algorithm, string-matching

I am trying to write a javascript algorithm that checks to see if an array of characters could make a given string.

I decided to go about this by writing a function that converts the array to a string so that I can call the .match() method on that string to search for the characters of the given string.

```
function arrStr(arr,str) {
cleanArray(arr).match(str) ? true : false

}

function cleanArray(arr){
    return arr.join('')
}
```

When I attempt to execute this algorithm, I keep getting "undefined". Anybody have any ideas as to why? Thank you

Comment: You have no `return` statement in `arrStr`

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from `arrStr()`

```
function arrStr(arr,str) {
   return cleanArray(arr).match(str) ? true : false

}

function cleanArray(arr){
    return arr.join('')
}
```